# webkit transform translateZ alternative for position fixed

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I have an application with a button.
when you click on said button, a dropdown menu appears which has the following css attribute:
 `position: fixed`

I've found the following work-around:
`-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`

When this style is applied, `position:fixed;` works as intended, but the issue is that the text in the drop-down menu crops up, when you apply:
`-webkit-transform: translateZ(100);`

Any number other than 0 fixes the cropped menu, but the `position: fixed` stops working.

Is there an alternative to `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to fix `position: fixed;` on Chrome, I can't seem to find one all posts I find tell me to use webkit transform translateZ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
 #link1{top: -15%!important;}
}
```

this works, it's a bit inconvenient but atleast it works.